# How to exclude a currently selected item from an exception handling

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# working on a project currently where I want to exclude an item that is edited from an exception. In this scenario a user can edit an appointment including the appointment, however; there can not be overlapping appointments. When I run my program and edit the appointment, the exception is checking against the appointment being edited which it shouldn't. Can someone advise me on how to do this?

```
foreach (var appt in AppointmentScreen.ListOfAppts)
{                    
    if (selectedStart <= appt.Start && selectedEnd > appt.Start && (!(SelectApptID >= 0)) || SelectApptID >= 0)
    {
        overlaping = true;
    }

    if (appt.Start <= selectedStart && appt.End > selectedStart && (!(SelectApptID >= 0)) || SelectApptID >= 0)
    {
        overlaping = true;
    }
}
```

if more information is needed please let me know. I will be checking periodically throughout the day.

thanks for all the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the appointment being edited have an unique id you can check against with?

If not what about add a Guid property to the appointment object and with a simple condition skip if it's current? Something like:

```
foreach (var appt in AppointmentScreen.ListOfAppts)
{
    if (appt.Id == CurrentAppt.Id) continue;  //this condition skips the appointment being edited
    if (selectedStart <= appt.Start && selectedEnd > appt.Start && (!(SelectApptID >= 0)) || SelectApptID >= 0)
    {
        overlaping = true;
    }

    if (appt.Start <= selectedStart && appt.End > selectedStart && ((SelectApptID >= 0)) || SelectApptID >= 0)
    {
        overlaping = true;
    }
}
```

In your Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    .
    .        
    .
}
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to work as I wanted it to!

Comment: well. You can mark this question as answered if you think so

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what SelectedApptId>=0 means but in order to verify if the current interval overlaps with any other interval you could do it like this:

`var overlapping = AppointmentScreen.ListOfAppts.Any(appt=> appt.Start <= selectedEnd && appt.End >= selectedStart);`